# About key API google maps

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I want to make a web app and an `android` app, using the same database for both.

The idea is, all users can add and remove markers on the same map for both user types (web app and android app). I can use `php` and `JavaScript` for the web app.

My question is: do I need to use two different Google Maps API keys for each app (if I want to use the same map and database)?

What database manager is recommended for this project? I am considering MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use two keys each for web and mobile app.

Keys are basically Server key, Browser key, iOS and Android key. your requirements come under both Browser and Android category.

You can read out more at "Public API access:" section at [API Key](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#api-keys).